# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

Ok this has really got me confused.

This query returns the expected results albeit with duplicate car_id numbers

```
SELECT car_id FROM `Updates` ORDER BY `updates`.`created` DESC
```

These 2 queries return the same set of results:

```
SELECT distinct `Updates`.`car_id` FROM `Updates` ORDER BY `updates`.`created` DESC

SELECT car_id FROM `Updates` GROUP BY car_id ORDER BY `updates`.`created` DESC
```

See below though as to how they differ:
[image: See below though as to how they differ:]

Comment: How many rows are returned? My guess they aren't missing but way back in the resultset. Do order by id to check.

Comment: @stryba You're right, it appears that the other ids are actually in the list just not in the copy I specfied - ORDER BY updates.created DESC Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is strictly relevant with your problem but:

```
SELECT DISTINCT car_id 
FROM Updates 
ORDER BY created DESC
```

is not valid standard SQL syntax. There may be many rows with same `car_id` and different `created` values. Which one should be used for the ordering?

Perhaps you want to rewrite the query so it returns meaningful results:

```
SELECT car_id 
FROM Updates
GROUP BY car_id 
ORDER BY MAX(created) DESC              --- or MIN(created)
                                        -- whatever suits you
```

Answer (score 1):

You're ordering by `updates.created`. Presumably this means that each distinct `carid` will come up, just not exactly where you expect it to. Try ordering by `carid` to perform the comparison.

Comment: You're right, it appears that the other ids are actually in the list just not in the copy I specfied - ORDER BY `updates`.`created` DESC

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Would Something Like This Work:

SELECT * FROM Updates GROUP BY car_id ORDER BY created DESC